# Filtering and grouping data onto new dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataset set and I am looking to display summarized results on a new data frame. So far I have the first two columns created which are all the unique IDs and the number of unique case numbers for that ID. Now I am looking to create additional columns that will display the "Code" for each case numbers as 1st case, 2nd case etc. columns. The logic is that the columns will display the the code that corresponds to a case number, if the case numbers are the same then it will first display the one with the earliest date, and then the later ones on the columns after it. And then the other "Code" for the different case numbers of the same ID after. Any help would be appreciated as I cannot figure out how to do it, thanks!

Desired result:

```
     ID        cases.unique        1st Case     2nd Case    3rd Case    4th Case
 1   100            1                715.10      724.50
 2   200            2                717.00      300.02      366.90      444.22
 3   300            1                717.00
 4   400            1                465.80      785.00
 5   500            1                309.00
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame("ID" = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500),
                "Case Number" = c(1111, 1111, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 9999, 1422, 1422, 1522), 
                "Date" = c("2013/07/15", "2013/09/23", "2016/06/21", "2016/09/18", "2016/10/20", "2016/08/06", "2017/08/21", "2016/08/23", "2016/08/24","2016/08/14"),
                "Code" = c(715.1, 724.5,717,366.9,444.22,300.02,717,465.8,785,309.0))
```

What I have so far:

```
x2 <- x %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(
    cases.unique = n_distinct(Case.Number)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Date = as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d")) %>%
  mutate(cases.unique = n_distinct(Case.Number), 
         cnmbr = paste0("Case ", row_number())) %>%
  distinct(ID, cases.unique, cnmbr, Code) %>%
  spread(cnmbr, Code)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID cases.unique `Case 1` `Case 2` `Case 3` `Case 4`
  <dbl>        <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1   100            1     715.     724.      NA       NA 
2   200            2     717      300.     367.     444.
3   300            1     717       NA       NA       NA 
4   400            1     466.     785       NA       NA 
5   500            1     309       NA       NA       NA
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I wanted, thank you! Another question, if there is another column that coprresponds to each "Code", how would I bring that into the new field for every case # column?

Comment: It's arranged by `Date` already and I think it'll suffice since it's grouped by ID and takes the rows corresponding to group only :-) @CoreyTan, you're welcome - am not completely sure what you mean, but if it is about bringing further information into the column names next to each `Case ...`, you'd need to put that into `paste0`.

Comment: sorry to clarify I mean theres a column that has a definition of what each Code means and I just wanted to bring that in next to each Code

Comment: You could try by adding in the `mutate` call above something like `Code = paste(Code, <yourcolumn>, sep = " ")`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(
  ID = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500),
  Case Number = c(1111, 1111, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 9999, 1422, 1422, 1522), 
  Date = c("2013/07/15", "2013/09/23", "2016/06/21", "2016/09/18", "2016/10/20", "2016/08/06", "2017/08/21", "2016/08/23", "2016/08/24","2016/08/14"),
  Code = c(715.1, 724.5,717,366.9,444.22,300.02,717,465.8,785,309.0)
)
x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    cases.unique = n_distinct(Case.Number),
    case_label = paste0(row_number(), "_case")
  ) %>%
  select(-Case.Number, -Date) %>%
  spread(case_label, Code)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [5]
#>      ID cases.unique `1_case` `2_case` `3_case` `4_case`
#>   <dbl>        <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1   100            1     715.     724.      NA       NA 
#> 2   200            2     717      367.     444.     300.
#> 3   300            1     717       NA       NA       NA 
#> 4   400            1     466.     785       NA       NA 
#> 5   500            1     309       NA       NA       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>